# InvalidArgumentException with 'session.save_path' within Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I tried to load this Bookingsystem (https://github.com/tkrebs/ep3-bs) on a websapce of bplaced.net.

After setup (no problems here) I tried to load the index.php and got a uncaught exception 'Zend\Session\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message ''session.save_path' is not a valid sessions-related ini setting...

I made an issue on github https://github.com/tkrebs/ep3-bs/issues/10 where it is explained.

It seems that the error is whithin the Zend-Framework 2 (see issue)

Has someone a solution to this problem?

--- EDIT: Solution ----

It has been revealed that the hoster don't allow to change session.save_path

So leaving the default for session.save_path solved the problem (see issue)

Answer (score 0):

The last comment on the issue you linked to actually says it's likely a web server configuration problem, not a ZF2 issue. The error you're getting from ZF is only triggered when `ini_set()` fails which basically confirms this.

If I had to guess I'd say your session folder is not writeable - you might want to check that you did step 2 of the installation instructions for this app: https://github.com/tkrebs/ep3-bs/blob/master/data/docs/install.txt

Comment: I know it's possible that it is just a config problem, but I'm not able do determine what to change on the config. The directory rights are all 777 (for debugging). So that shouldn't be the problem but I'll check. Can you tell me where I can find ini_set()?

Comment: `ini_set()` is a PHP function: http://php.net/ini-set. You could try uploading a standalone PHP file that just contains a call to `ini_set('session.save_path', '/path/to/your/data/session');` - that might give you a more helpful error.

Comment: Tried to run local on a linux machine. It works. So I guess it's a config problem. Any ideas what could be misconfigured? (I know there are many possibilities)